# Echo Script Alert in mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hi I am trying to make a delete script it was working fine when user click on Delete it delete that post and popup alter that post has been deleted and then redirect to their main page but after converting this script into mysqli it is working fine but it's not showing popup alter and also not redirecting.

**Here is my delete.php script**

```
<?php 

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123","user");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
if(isset($_GET['del'])){

    $delete_id = $_GET['del'];

$delete_query = mysqli_query($con,"delete from save_data where ID='$delete_id'")
    or die(mysql_error()); 

if (mysqli_query($con, $delete_query)) {

echo "<script>alert('Image Has been Deleted')</script>";
    echo "<script>window.open('pimage.php','_self')</script>";

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: You are missing semi colons after JavaScript statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why you are executing query twice? and you forgot semicolon in script tag

try to do like this..

```
      $delete_query = mysqli_query($con,"delete from save_data where ID='$delete_id'")
or die(mysql_error()); 

  if ($delete_query) {

     echo "<script>alert('Image Has been Deleted');</script>";
     echo "<script>window.open('pimage.php','_self');</script>";
}
```

hope it may solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, You have missed to ass `;` in script. Also you have executed the `mysqli_query` multiple times, instead use one time.

```
    if ($delete_query) {            
           echo "<script>alert('Image Has been Deleted'); window.open('pimage.php','_self');</script>"; 
    }
```

Comment: what is the difference between `echo "<script>alert('Image Has been Deleted');</script>";
    echo "<script>window.open('pimage.php','_self');</script>";` and your's

Comment: @ling.s To avoid the extra tags.

Comment: To avoid the extra tags, you are adding two extra lines

Comment: @ling.s , Now I have added into single line :)

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
echo "<script>alert('Image Has been Deleted')</script>";
echo "<script>window.open('pimage.php','_self')</script>";
```

To:

```
echo "<script>alert('Image Has been Deleted');</script>";
echo "<script>window.open('pimage.php','_self');</script>";
```

Also you are running the SQL statement twice so if will always be false because it is already deleted. So change `$delete_query` to:

```
$delete_query = "delete from save_data where ID='$delete_id'");
```